# Setting a SSL + Happstack Server Example fails with file error

Tags: haskell, ssl, web, happstack

I trying to write a simple **Happstack** application that uses **SSL**. With this source code:

```
module Main where

import Happstack.Server( ok )
import Happstack.Server.SimpleHTTPS( TLSConf(..), nullTLSConf, simpleHTTPS )

conf :: TLSConf
conf = nullTLSConf{
  tlsPort = 8011
  , tlsCert = "server.crt"
  , tlsKey = "server.key"
  }

main :: IO ()
main = simpleHTTPS nullTLSConf $ ok "Hello, World!"
```

It compiles, but, When I run as a normal user, I get:

```
mytest: bind: permission denied (Permission denied)
```

When I run as *root* I get:

```
mytest: user error (error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory)
```

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I founded the error:

It should be:

```
main = simpleHTTPS conf $ ok "Hello, World!"
```